# How do I make the value closer to the summation?

Tags: equations, formatting

```
\begin{align}
    \sum_{e\in abzbb}x_{p}-l_p\sum_{e\in abdab}x_{p}=3
\end{align}
```

[image]
Since my **abdab** is so big, it separates the **l_p** so much from the summation. What I would like is the following: it should be close, but it **shouldn't depend on the size** of whatever goes in the summation starting sum.
[image]

From above, instead of **abdab** we have just **a**, but I want the same distance regardless of what is underneath.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `mathtools` loaded (needless to load `amsmath` in this case):

```
\begin{align}
    \smashoperator{\sum_{e\in abzbb}}x_{p}-l_p\smashoperator{\sum_{e\in abdab}}x_{p}=3
\end{align}
```

[image]